# Errors with apostrophes and lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to insert brackets into the start and end of a list made from two lists placed together through `.extend()` so it prints like so: `('dog','cat','mouse')('pig, 'cow', 'sheep')`. However the output I'm getting is `'dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'pig', 'cow', 'sheep'`. Whilst you can insert a bracket in many ways- `"("` , `chr(40)` etc)- the obvious flaw is that the brackets output in quotations.

`.join` I understand can be used for whole lists. However, I have not found a way to use it for one item- does such a way exist?

My code looks like this:

```
all_animals= []
house_animals= ['dog','cat','mouse']
farm_animals= ['pig', 'cow', 'sheep']
all_animals.extend(house_animals)
all_animals.extend(farm_animals)
print(str(all_animals)[1:-1])
```

**EDIT**

In a similar vein, If a *dictionary* features an apostrophe (') [bear with me: it gets to lists] the output is affected as it prints that particular word in quotes ("") rather that the normal apostrophes. EXAMPLE: living_beings= `{"Reptile":"Snake's","mammal":"whale", "Other":"bird"}` and if you use the following code (which I need to):

```
new= []
for i in living_beings:
    r=living_beings[i]
    new.append(r)
```

then the output is "snake's", 'whale', 'bird' (Note the difference between the first and other outputs). So My question is: How to stop the apostrophes affecting output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your list to tuples and an put them into a list before printing:

```
house_animals = ['dog','cat','mouse']
farm_animals = ['pig', 'cow', 'sheep']
all_animals = [tuple(house_animals), tuple(farm_animals)]

print(''.join(str(x) for x in all_animals))
```

Output:

```
('dog', 'cat', 'mouse')('pig', 'cow', 'sheep')
```

Alternate solution closer to your approach but with `append`

```
all_animals= []
house_animals= ['dog','cat','mouse']
farm_animals= ['pig', 'cow', 'sheep']
all_animals.append(house_animals)
all_animals.append(farm_animals)
print(''.join(str(tuple(x)) for x in all_animals))
```

Output:

```
('dog', 'cat', 'mouse')('pig', 'cow', 'sheep')
```

## EDIT

This is just the way Python represents strings:

```
>>> "snake's"
"snake's"
>>> "whale"
'whale'
```

It has nothing particularly to do with dictionaries or lists.

For your example:

```
living_beings= {"Reptile":"Snake's","mammal":"whale", "Other":"bird"} 
new= []
for i in living_beings:
    r=living_beings[i]
    new.append(r)
```

you can format the strings to get rid of the quotes all together:

```
print('[{}]'.format(', '.join(new)))

[Snake's, whale, bird]
```

Answer (score 1):

First consider adding the farm/house_animals as a `list` rather than each animal individually:

```
all_animals = []
all_animals.append(house_animals)
all_animals.append(farm_animals)
```

Then the print statement you are looking for can look like this:

```
print(''.join(['{0}'.format(tuple(animal)) for animal in all_animals]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be:

```
"".join(
     [str(tuple(house_animals)), str(tuple(farm_animals))]
)
```

Output:

```
('dog', 'cat', 'mouse')('pig', 'cow', 'sheep')
```